# React Typescript: Why is my canvas image resize component creating small blurry images from large crisp images?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas

I've made this little image resizer and I can't figure out why the images it creates are blurry, especially when I use a large image.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface PropsInterface {
  placeholder: string;
  resizeTo: number;
  blob?: Function;
  base64?: Function;
}

const Photo: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    imageURL: props.placeholder,
  });

  const {
    imageURL,
  } = state;

  const dataURLToBlob = (dataURL: string) => {
    const parts = dataURL.split(';base64,');
    const contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    const raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    const rawLength = raw.length;
    const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);
    for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
      uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
  };

  const resizeImage = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.currentTarget.files) {
      const file = event.currentTarget.files[0];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.onload = async (imageEvent) => {
          const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          const maxSize = props.resizeTo;
          let width = image.width;
          let height = image.height;
          if (width > height && width > maxSize) {
              height *= maxSize / width;
              width = maxSize;
          } else if (height > maxSize) {
              width *= maxSize / height;
              height = maxSize;
          }
          canvas.width = width;
          canvas.height = height;
          const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext('2d')!;
          ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
          ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
          const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
          const resizedImage = dataURLToBlob(dataUrl);
          setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, imageURL: dataUrl }));
          if (props.blob) props.blob(resizedImage);
          if (props.base64) props.base64(dataUrl);
        };
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='photo'>
      <label>
        <img
          src={imageURL}
          alt='your first name initial'
          className='photo--preview'
        />
        <input
          type='file'
          id='photo'
          name='photo'
          accept='image/png, image/jpeg'
          onChange={resizeImage}
        ></input>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export { Photo };
```

I use it by adding

```
<Photo placeholder={placeholder} resizeTo={60} blob={blob} />
```

Where `placeholder` is a URL to an image I want to display initially `resizeTo` is the size in pixels I want to resize the image to and `blob` is the name of the function that it returns a blob to.

Left is my image resizer and right is from another website.
The image from another website is 180px square, So I set `resizeTo` 180 and the result can be seen on the left.

The left image is 180 width but not 180pix high, maybe this is why the quality looks worse? How to crop the image to 180x180? so we can make a fair comparison?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but you want to resize the image freely without image lost? You current code is drawing the input image onto a canvas which is smaller than the input, this might be the result of the data lost. Maybe you should 1) Drawn into the canvas with same size 2) set <image src> to the data url 3) then resize the <image> instead of the canvase

Comment: When I add an image that is a similar size to the `resizeTo` size, the quality is fine, but if I add a really big image like 4k and try to resize it to 150px it looks like trash –

Comment: Of course it will look like trash. You destination do not have enough space to store incoming information, thus some information is lost. Imagine that you are trying to pour 2L of water into a 1L bottle. Some liquid will bound to be lost. Your canvas need to be as large as the incoming image. Resize the `<img>` not the canvas

Comment: When I compare this to other sites, it looks really bad ill make an example to show the same image being upload and the two different results

Comment: Can you post the image url with which you have resized the above images? Also, looks like left and right image are resized using different images.

Comment: They are the same image, but the one on the right is cropped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your file is loaded, you should save the loaded data as source of truth, and if you want to retain all the information, the source of truth cannot be modified.

Instead, you create a view for source, and change the view instead. In my example below, the source of truth is `this.state.data` and the view is the `<img>` tag. The slider is used to modify the img and the source is not changed.

See the code below.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ypoon196/yjprgfch/25/

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        // Base64
        data: "",
        // Original W/H
        imageWidth: 0,
        imageHeight: 0,
        // resized W/H
        currWidth: 0,
        currHeight: 0,
        lockAspect: true,
      };
  };

  handleFileChange(evt) {
    const file = evt.target.files[0];
    if (!!file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        // Save to a temp location to get the height and width
        const tmp = new Image();
        tmp.onload = () => {
          // Only display everythin when all is loaded
          const height = tmp.height;
          const width = tmp.width;
          this.setState({
            data: reader.result,
            imageHeight: height,
            imageWidth: width,
            currHeight: height,
            currWidth: width
          })
        };
        tmp.src = reader.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }

  handleSliderChange(type, evt) {
    const val = evt.target.value;
    const { lockAspect, imageHeight, imageWidth } = this.state;
    switch (type) {
        case "height":
        if (lockAspect) {
            const ratio = imageHeight / imageWidth;
          const otherVal = val / ratio;
            this.setState(prevState => {
            return { currHeight: val, currWidth: otherVal }
          });
        } else {
            this.setState(prevState => {
            return { currHeight: val }
          });
        }       
        break;
      case "width":
        if (lockAspect) {
            const ratio = imageHeight / imageWidth;
          const otherVal = val * ratio;
            this.setState(prevState => {
            return { currHeight: otherVal, currWidth: val }
          });
        } else {
            this.setState(prevState => {
            return { currWidth: val }
          });
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  handleAspectToggle() {
    this.setState(({lockAspect}) => {
        return {lockAspect: !lockAspect}
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { data, imageHeight, imageWidth, currWidth, currHeight, lockAspect } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={evt => this.handleFileChange(evt)} accept="image/*"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Height</label>
            <input 
              type="range"
              min="1" 
              max={imageHeight} 
              value={currHeight}
              onChange={evt => this.handleSliderChange("height", evt)}
            />
            <span>{ currHeight }</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Width</label>
            <input 
              type="range"
              min="1" 
              max={imageWidth} 
              value={currWidth}
              onChange={evt => this.handleSliderChange("width", evt)}
            />
            <span>{ currWidth }</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Lock Aspect</label>
            <input 
              type="checkbox"
              checked={lockAspect}
              onChange={() => this.handleAspectToggle()}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <img height={currHeight} width={currWidth} src={data}/>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: The answer here doesn't do any resizing at all

Comment: Fixed some bug.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you reduce an image you will loose some information.  One thing to consider while resizing the image is Aspect Ratio and i believe this part of the code handles it

```
if (width > height && width > maxSize) {
     height *= maxSize / width;
     width = maxSize;
} else if (height > maxSize) {
     width *= maxSize / height;
     height = maxSize;
}
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

Other than that, the image on the right is not just resized but also cropped.  If you look at the top right corner some part of the clouds are missing.  You cannot compare the left and right, check if original image and the resized image's aspect ratio matches, if not fix it.